# Freezing ready to poach eggs

Tags: eggs, poaching

I am generally a bit strapped for time, so in an attempt to maximise my time my plan is to crack eggs into clingfilm and tie them so they make poaching pods, freeze them, and drop them into water when needed.

Has anyone tried to freeze these poaching pods and then poach the eggs from frozen?

Comment: I don't understand how trying to poach an egg from frozen saves time over just cracking an egg into simmering water.

Comment: Indeed, you have many added steps that could only waste time.

Comment: sorry for not getting back earlier. consider this, not the freshest of eggs and a lack of skill in the culinary arts,

by placing them into clingfilm i find i can make a pretty decent poached egg without it breaking in any way. doing this means i also dont need to watch them in any way either. the idea of freezing them was more to prolong their life then anything else so i can prepare a large batch and cook them as required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work from a safety standpoint, unfortunately, freezing alters the property of the yolk.  So, you will likely not get the runny yolk that you would expect in a poached egg, it will be more solid, like a hard boiled egg.  Why not poach your eggs for the week and store them in the refrigerator, then reheat each morning?  According to [The Food Lab](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/10/the-food-lab-how-to-poach-eggs-for-a-party.html) you can poach eggs and store them, with no loss of quality, for 5 days.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it looks like a great solution. i'll be giving it a bash in a few min.